# Oracle Forms: Restore DB Backup Through Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Hope you are doing well ...
I am facing an issue in oracle forms where i would like to write following code
But I feel that it is not connecting to system and do not drop user... I have checked it to get login with current user

```
DECLARE
    V_USR VARCHAR2(20):=NULL;
    V_PWD VARCHAR2(20):=NULL;
BEGIN
    V_USR := USER;
    V_PWD := GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(PASSWORD);
IF :PATH IS NULL THEN
        MESSAGE('Please select backup file to import.');
        MESSAGE('Please select backup file to import.');
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
END IF;
LOGOUT;
LOGON('SYSTEM','MANAGER@ORC');
FORMS_DDL('DROP USER '||V_USR||' CASCADE');
FORMS_DDL('CREATE USER '||V_USR||' IDENTIFIED BY '||V_PWD);
FORMS_DDL('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO '||V_USR);
FORMS_DDL('GRANT DBA TO '||V_USR);
host('imp userid='||V_USR||'/'||V_PWD||' fromuser='||V_USR||' touser='||V_USR||' file = '||:path||' log=d:\import_log.txt');
LOGOUT;
LOGON(V_USR,V_PWD||'@'||'ORC');
NEXT_ITEM;
END;
```

Waiting for your kind response

Answer (score 0):

> But I feel that it is not connecting to system
>
> `LOGON('SYSTEM','MANAGER@ORC');`

Indeed. Database name goes along with username, not password.

For example:

```
SQL> connect scott@pdb1       --> see? with username
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
```

so I'd try `LOGON('SYSTEM@ORC','MANAGER')` (the same goes at the end of script you posted, when you're logging in as newly created user).

---

By the way, that's a really powerful user, with all privileges and DBA role as well. Are you sure-sure you want to do that?

Comment: I hv tried it with LOGON('SYSTEM@ORC','MANAGER') But it is not working and showing error in attachment/log file Please help to resolve it ... Remember one thing I am running this form with scott/tiger user
User scott is dropped and created new one and give privileges DBA then import db dump file .. pls guide